# String Replacement for Items in a List

Tags: python, list

```
filenames = ["program.c", "stdio.hpp", "sample.hpp", "a.out", "math.hpp", "hpp.out"]
```

I want to replace the .hpp with .h.

```
y=[]
for x in filenames:
    if '.hpp' in x:
        x=x.replace('hpp','h')
        y.append(x)
    else:
        y.append(x)
print(y)
```

Is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it in a single line:

```
filenames = [item.replace('.hpp', '.h') for item in filenames]
```

This gives the same output

Answer (score 0):

This solution works:

```
filenames = [filename.replace('.hpp', '.h') for filename in filenames]
```

If you're interested, you can read more about list comprehensions [here.](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html)